Why are “asked” and “closed” dates rounded differently?
I recently asked a question on InformationSecurity Meta, because I’d observed a particular question that was apparently closed a month before it was asked.
From a mod there, I found out that the “close date” of a question is rounded up to the nearest integer (e.g. 5 months ago,) whereas the “ask date” is either rounded down or to the closest date.
Why? Why are they handled differently?

Why? My not-so-wild guess it that because the code showing the "asked" date was written by Dev1, and the code showing the "closed" date was written (or overwritten) by Dev2, and each developer has their own style of programming which includes how they round numbers or dates.

I assume they still use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/calculate-relative-time-in-c-sharp  which suggests it always rounds down. Not sure  where or why they deviated.

Not sure if this is worth being tagged as [tag:bug] due to finding inconsistent rounding behaviour.

Not sure if this answers why or not, but "Both the Asked date and the Closed date at the top of the page use their own bespoke date formatters that are different from the standard one used on things like comments. Each has specific strengths, weaknesses, and quirks, and merging the two is a much more complex discussion."

@HenryEcker it's very hard to read your comment as it's formatted as link, with underline. Please link only some keyword or even better, something like "as Brian said in [this answer]({link here})", and not the whole answer.

@ShadowWizard without having a matching format (such as method of rounding) to develop off? Sounds slightly unusual but I guess that’s probably the only(?) explanation. Thanks

@rene thanks. Doesn’t answer why, but does explain how.

@ChesterGillon I wouldn’t say it’s a bug, because it isn’t a mistake. A feature-request maybe, but not a bug. Thanks anyway.

As for bug or not, I'd say it's a bug in the core logic of the code design, that allows such inconsistencies, in great many place all around Stack Exchange sites. It's not any single developer's fault, it's the result of not having a strict mechanism to build unified code from the beginning. Way too late to "fix" that, so technically it can't be considered an ordinary bug. When it comes to tags here, I'd say tagging as a bug is fine, but so is any other tag.

@ShadowWizard that’s a very good point.
